# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to display content of http request with python, I've tried this

```
page= requests.request(method="get",url=url, params= parameters)
j_results=json.loads(page.text)
print (page)
```

But I get this:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-42-9f7940edb2de> in <module>()
 13 page= requests.request(method="get",url=url, params= parameters)
 14 
 ---> 15 j_results=json.loads(page.text)
 16 print (page.text)
 17 

C:\Users\sony\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls,       object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
316             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
317             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not  kw):
--> 318         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
319     if cls is None:
320         cls = JSONDecoder
```

I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your traceback is showing a different thing than the code you posted.

```
# Your code snippet
j_results=json.load(page.text)

# Your traceback
j_results=json.load(page)

# You should be using the `loads` function (which loads from a string)
j_result = json.loads(page.text)
```

Change your code to match what you posted in your snippet. Alternatively, if you know the response is JSON already, you can use

```
j_result = page.json()
```

Comment: even with
j_results=json.load(page.text)
I still get the same error

Comment: I updated my answer. I missed the fact that you were using `json.load` instead of `json.loads`. The latter loads the JSON from a string, the former loads from a file-like object. You could still just use `page.json()` instead though.